# ¿Cómo hago para que al presionar ENTER en una celda que esta siendo editada de un jTable me agrege otra fila?

Tags: java, jtable

Buenas, estoy haciendo un `JTable` en el cual se pueda agregar productos mediante el código de barras. Lo que quiero hacer es que luego de leer un código de barras, automáticamente me cree una fila para agregar más productos. Por otro lado, también quiero que al presionar ENTER en una celda que estoy editando, me agregue una nueva fila. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar una fila creo que podrias simplemente poner:

`nombreDeTuTabla.addRow(new Object[]{"","","",""});`

al final de la parte que lee el codigo de barras.

Para lo del enter:

```
private void jTable_RowsKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
   if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            nombreDeTuTabla.addRow(new Object[]{"","","",""});
        }
}
```

en teoria esto deberia de funcionar, en teoria...